# Android Studio asks Import Settings

Tags: android, android-studio, settings

Recently when I opened Android Studio I see message that its asks import settings, but i runned Android Studio not first time. I clicked cancel and It started as first time, in project manager there is not any of my projects and It suggested download SDKs and Emulator but I have downloaded them before. And now today the situation is same. It asks import setting but i dont know where are they. Can you please say where is located settings file of android studio default? And why Android Studio show me that message that i should import settings?

I tried to set location of Android Studio folder but it says that i set the current Android Studio config directory

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Usually there are 2-4 bigger AS updates a year and each of this bigger updates has it's own settings folder. If you start such a new version for first time settings are migrated (copied). On the other hand this also means that your user data folder contains at least one now unused AS settings folder. Each folder can contain a few GB of cached artifacts and other data...